# Bind Semantic UI radio checkboxes to Meteor event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, semantic-ui

I have a few Semantic UI radio checkboxes:

```
<div class="inline fields">
    <label>When: </label>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="publish" tabindex="0" class="hidden" checked="checked">
            <label>Now</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="publish" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
            <label>Later</label>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
         <div class="ui radio checkbox">
             <input type="radio" name="publish" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
             <label>On specified date</label>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I can pick up a change to them in the templates onRendered function like this:

```
$('.ui.checkbox').checkbox();

$(".ui.checkbox").checkbox('setting', 'onChange', function () {
    alert('fire!');
});
```

But I would like to use Meteor events to keep my code clean, I tried the following but it does not work:

```
Template['article'].events({
    'change .ui.checkbox' : function () {
        alert('fire!');
    }
});
```

I also tried `onChange` instead.

Any clue if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Possible if you are using the package `manuel:viewmodel`. the package has implemented MVVM for Meteor

For Example Let us Show a Button as Primary when a checkbox is selected and normal when unselected.

The Html Code Will be

```
<template name="checked">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: showPrimary"/>Show button as primary
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button data-bind="class: { btn-primary: showPrimary }">The Button!</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the Javascript Code will be

```
Template.checked.viewmodel({
  showPrimary: false
});
```

This way we are binding the value of `showPrimary` to the class of the Button.

For More information please Refer http://viewmodel.meteor.com/

Hope this Helps !